# C++: running gdb in linux shell script

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell, gdb

I have a small C++ program `my-program`. When I run `my-program` directly

```
./my-program arg1
```

everything is ok. I don't get any errors. Besides I have `my-script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
my-program $1
```

When I run this script directly:

```
./my-script.sh arg1
```

I don't get any errors.

The problem appears when `my-script.sh` is run from other linux processes. In this case I sometimes(!) get `Segmentation fault` error. What I did: I added the `-g` switch to c++ compiler and edited `my-script.sh`, so it became:

```
#!/bin/sh
gdb -batch -x gdb-script --args my-program $1
```

In `gdb-script` I wrote:

```
run
```

However, I still can't find the line which causes `Segmentation fault` error. How can I make dgb print the stacktrace to some file after error? Or maybe there are ways to get the place in program which causes this error?

Comment: Add `bt` (or `backtrace` or `where`) to your "gdb-script" file? - if you have many threads, you may want to do more to print all stacks for all threads - I'm not sure what that command is, but I know it can be done.

Comment: Try running under valgrind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem appears when my-script.sh is run from other linux processes.

Your script contains several mistakes:

1. It will only work if the directory in which `my-program` resides is on your `$PATH`.
2. It does not pass arguments to `my-program` correctly. In particular, only the the first argument is passed, and if that argument contains spaces, it will be split into words and will become multiple arguments by the time `my-program` is invoked.

To fix this, do something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec $(dirname "$0")/my-program "$@"
```

> How can I make dgb print the stacktrace to some file after error?

Append `where` command to the `gdb-script`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if you have some limit for core dumps set in your system:

```
ulimit -c
```

If it is '0', you won't get any core dumps generated.
Set:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

And then run the program as long as you get 'Segmentation fault'. Then you should have core dump file generated.